# Java - validate operator

Tags: java, validation, methods, operator-keyword

I written the below program, but confused on part b of the question.
Question is-
Write a program that will evaluate simple expressions such as 17 + 3 and 3.14159 *
4.7. The expressions are to be typed in by the user. The input always consists of a number, followed by an operator, followed by another number. The operators that are allowed are +, -, *, and /. You are not required to perform data validation here as it is to be done in part (b) below. Your program output must show the expression entered together with the result (e.g. 17 + 3 = 20).

Part B:
Modify your program in part (a) above to validate the operator entered. The program repeats for the input until a valid operator is entered. You are required to make use of method for the validation.

Here's what i wrote

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaCalculator
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
       double digit1;
       double digit2;
       double total;
       String operator1; 

       System.out.print("Enter 1st number: ");
       digit1 = console.nextDouble();

       System.out.print("Enter the operator: ");
       operator1=console.next();    

       System.out.print("Enter 2nd number: ");
       digit2 = console.nextDouble();

        if (operator1.equals("-"))
      {
        total = digit1-digit2;
        System.out.println(+digit1+ "-" +digit2+ "=" +total);
      }
      else if (operator1.equals("+"))
      {
        total = digit1+digit2;
        System.out.println(+digit1+ "+" +digit2+ "=" +total);
      }
      else if (operator1.equals("*"))
      {
        total = digit1*digit2;
        System.out.println(+digit1+ "*" +digit2+ "=" +total);
      }
      else if (operator1.equals("+"))
      {
        total = digit1/digit2;
        System.out.println(+digit1+ "/" +digit2+ "=" +total);
      }

     }

}
```

Just got started out with Java, please bear with me or ignorance here in this question.
On which line should I get started on Part B to validate the operator?

Comment: This won't compile, also you didn't really ask a question.

Comment: i manage to compile them.
stucked on part B to validate the operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have rewritten your code. I hope this will fulfill your expectation.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
   Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
   double digit1;
   double digit2;
   double total;
   String operator = ""; 
   boolean repeatFlag = true;
   while(repeatFlag)   {
     System.out.print("Enter a valid operator(+, -, /, *): ");
     operator = console.next();
   if(!(operator.equals("+") || 
          operator.equals("-") || operator.equals("/") || operator.equals("*"))) 
     {
    repeatFlag=true;
    continue;
     }
        repeatFlag = false;
   }

   System.out.print("Enter 1st number: ");
   digit1 = console.nextDouble();
   System.out.print("Enter 2nd number: ");
   digit2 = console.nextDouble();

  if (operator.equals("-"))
  {
    total = digit1-digit2;
    System.out.println(+digit1+ "-" +digit2+ "=" +total);
  }
  else if (operator.equals("+"))
  {
    total = digit1+digit2;
    System.out.println(+digit1+ "+" +digit2+ "=" +total);
  }
  else if (operator.equals("*"))
  {
    total = digit1*digit2;
    System.out.println(+digit1+ "*" +digit2+ "=" +total);
  }
  else if (operator.equals("/"))
  {
    total = digit1/digit2;
    System.out.println(+digit1+ "/" +digit2+ "=" +total);
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is confusing there? Is it the valid operator part?
If so, you can use a loop which goes on and on until the input is one of the valid operator. Something like that:

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
double digit1 = console.nextDouble();
String operator1;
boolean nonValidOperator = true;
while(nonValidOperator){
  operator1 = console.next();
  if(operator1.equals("-"){
    nonValidOperator = false; // so the program continues
  }else if(operator1.equals("+"){
    nonValidOperator = false;
  }
}
double digit2 = console.nextDouble();

if(operator1.equals("-"){
  System.out.println(digit1-digit2);
}else if(operator1.equals("+"){
  System.out.println(digit1+digit2);
}
```

So that the loop is on the operator part until the user input one of your valid operator

Comment: Hi Barbe, thanks!
It's the part where i got stucked because I dont know how to validate a string operator.
I tried if else statement, but what should the conditions be for +-*/ ?

Comment: You got the correct way to do it in your code   operator1.equals("-");   you just need a loop in case the user doesn't input a correct operator

Comment: Hmmm. I wrote it like this -
     System.out.print("Enter 1st number: ");
           digit1 = console.nextDouble();
           
           System.out.print("Enter the operator: ");
           operator1=console.next();
           
           System.out.print("Enter 2nd number: ");
           digit2 = console.nextDouble();

how should my boolean be declared at?

Comment: I am editing my piece of code to show you how I would do it for the user input part

Comment: Thanks!
Let me redit my script and show you whats on mine after some figuring.

Comment: Confused as to check the value of the operator first, before prompting to do the calculation

Comment: I tried your script before. However inside the if else code, there is digit2 variation declared inside. it wont recognise it though

Comment: You don't actually need to know the digit2 input inside the operator loop. When the operator is chosen, the program get out of the loop but still knows what was the chosen operator because it was stored in String operato1. So after the loop is finished, the user is asked to input digit2. After it's done you can output the result

Comment: I edited the piece of code so it ouputs your results after the user has chosen both values and the operator